# Can I assign specific event hooks to specific Okta applications?

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

Can I assign specific `event hooks` to specific Okta applications?

I created a `user is unassigned event hook` but I'm receiving the event hook request when the user is unassigned from all Okta applications.

I would like to send out specific unassignment event hooks to `different URLs` depending on which application the user was unassigned from. So I would like to attach specific `event hooks` to specific applications so that the external applications can handle deprovisioning on their side.

Is this possible?

Looking through the documentation, it does not appear that is possible
https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/event-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

Okta has open beta in progress for "conditional hooks" where you can filter events to be delivered to the hook endpoint. It might be something you can use to configure multiple hooks of the same type but different URLs for different applications based on the filter expression.

Check you Settings -> Features -> Open Betas if you have it