# What is the best way to deprovision a user from an application after they have been unassigned in Okta?

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

In Okta, I can unassign a user from an application but then the application will not know that the user has been unassigned and will still show the user in the application.

What is the best way to "alert" the application that the user has been unassigned so that the application can remove the user appropriately?

I looked at `event hooks` but event hooks send out a `user unassigned` event hook when the user is unassigned from any apps. I want to send a specific event hook out to the external application specifically for that application so that application can remove the user accordingly from their side.
https://help.okta.com/en-us/Content/Topics/automation-hooks/event-hooks-main.htm?cshid=ext-event-hooks

I see I can also download reports (recent unassignments) but that is a very manual process.

Is there an api endpoint I can hit from the external app to compare the users?

What do you suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237747/can-i-assign-specific-event-hooks-to-specific-okta-applications/75238081#75238081 ?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use SCIM provisioning mechanism, where only events related to a particular application will be sent out to your configured endpoint on the application side.

Please check out [Okta SCIM documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/scim/)